# Usage of I and Myself

Tags: grammar

Mail : "Who will be doing the validation?"
Reply : "Myself and Sarah will be doing validation"

I believe the usage of myself is incorrect here. It should be "Sarah and I will be doing validation". Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As a subject, use _I_, indeed. And you are also correct about moving _Sarah_ forward - it's often seen as inappropriate to put yourself first in an enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. "Myself" is a reflexive pronoun, unsuitable as a subject.